# Ruby on rails LoadError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to debug my log's with the following line:

```
<%= debug $pvp_user.pvp_death_logs %>
```

**The error I am receiving:**

> Unable to autoload constant PvpDeathLog, expected /var/www/rails/ourapp/app/models/pvp_death_log.rb to define it

**models/pvp_user.rb**

```
class Pvp_user < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :pvp_death_logs
end
```

**models/pvp_death_log.rb**

```
class Pvp_death_log < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :pvp_user
end
```

**controllers/player_controller.rb**

```
class PlayerController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def show
    user = Mc_user.find_by username: params[:id]
    if !user
        flash[:status] = FALSE
        flash[:alert] = 'we couldn\'t find that user.'
    else
        pvp_user = Pvp_user.find_by username: params[:id]
        if !pvp_user
            flash[:status_pvp] = FALSE
            flash[:alert_pvp] = 'No player vs player profile found.'
        else
            flash[:status_pvp] = TRUE
            $pvp_user = pvp_user
        end

        flash[:status] = TRUE
        $user = user
    end
  end
end
```

**views/player/show.html.erb**

```
<%= debug $pvp_user.pvp_death_logs %>
```

**Mysql database: pvp_users**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJXL8.png

**Mysql database: pvp_death_log**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5UNcr.png

Comment: I see some non-styleguide/convention-things which may lead to problems. First of all, models are camelCase, not underscored. Seconds, you're misusing `flash` a bit. Third, what's the reason to use a global variable `$user` instead of an instance variable (`@user`)?

Comment: Thanks, I changed the things you said. I also had to add a 's' to the end of my table name. Now it works.

Comment: Rails has a lot of "magic happens here" tricks that you just have to get used to. Once you've learned them all, though, it's pretty easy to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your classes' naming is inconsistent with Ruby standards. Classes and modules names should be in CamelCase:

```
class PvpUser
  # (...)
end

class PvpDeathLog
  # (...)
end
```